# Solving a puzzle using logic programming Prolog

Tags: prolog

Below is a puzzle from an old puzzle book , I am trying to solve this using logic programming language prolog.

> In the Plain City High School the classes in chemistry, history,
> Latin, and mathematics are taught, though not necessarily
> respectively, by Mr. Ames, Mr. Brown, Miss Clark, and Miss Davis.
> According to the school's yearbook,
>
> clue 1.) When they were in college the Latin teacher and the
> mathematics teacher won first prize in an allcampus tango contest.
>
> clue 2.) Mrs. Ames is president of the Plain City P.T.A.
>
> clue 3.) The chemistry teacher and the mathematics teacher were
> roommates in college.
>
> clue 4.) The chemistry teacher is also the football coach.
>
> clue 5.) The history teacher and the Latin teacher are engaged to each
> other.
>
> clue 6.) Mr. Ames, Mr. Brown, and Miss Clark went to different
> colleges.
>
> However, as everyone knows, a high school annual contains a certain
> amount of school gossip in addition to its factual summary of the
> year's activities, and hence is not always completely reliable. In the
> present case exactly five of the statements given are true and one is
> false.
>
> What subject does each person teach?

I have translated the puzzle into Prolog . But I am missing something because I am getting many answers instead of 4 or 6 answers .

```
  citizen(L):-L=[[a,_,_,_],[b,_,_,_],[c,_,_,_],[d,_,_,_]],
  Gender = [male, f], 
  Colleges = [college1, college2, college3],
  Subject = [latin, maths, hist, chem ],
  clue1(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject),
  clue2(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject),
  not(clue3(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject)),
  clue4(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject),
  clue5(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject),
  clue6(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject).

   clue1(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-
            member([_,latin,G11,C11],L),
            member([_,maths,G12,C12],L),
  member(C11,Colleges), member(C12,Colleges), C11 = C12,
  member(G11, Gender), member(G12, Gender), G11 \= G12.
  
  clue2(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-
            member([a,S21,male,_],L),
  member(S21, Subject),S21  \=  latin, S21  \=  hist.

  clue3(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-
            member([_,chem,G31,C31],L),
            member([_,maths,G32,C32],L), 
  member(G31, Gender), member(G32, Gender),G31 = G32,
  member(C31,Colleges), member(C32,Colleges),C31 = C32.              

  clue4(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-member([_,chem,male,_],L).

  clue5(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-
            member([_,hist,G51,_],L),
            member([_,latin,G52,_],L),
    member(G51, Gender),  member(G52, Gender),  G51 \= G52.

  clue6(L,Gender,Colleges,Subject) :-
            member([a,_,_,C41],L),
            member([b,_,_,C42],L),
            member([c,_,_,C43],L),
    member(C41,Colleges),member(C42,Colleges),member(C43,Colleges),
      C41 \= C42, C41 \= C43, C43 \= C42.
```

I can not find the missing point.  Please help me..

Below it edited version of question with more help.

```
  Below is a word problem. You can use tuples of the form      
  [name,subject,gender,college] since all the clues are about these four things.
In Plain City High, chem, math, latin, and history are taught, not nec. 
respectively, by Mr. Ames, Mr Brown, Miss Clark, and Miss Davis.       
 Find who teaches what, given that precisely one of the following clues is wrong.

 clue 1.the Latin and math teachers won a tango contest in college
        (can conclude they went to same college, and were of diff. gender)
 clue 2. Mrs. Ames is pres. of the PTA 
        (must interpret this to mean that Ames is not engaged)
 clue 3. chem and math were roommates in college
         (can conclude they are of same gender)
 clue 4. chem teacher coaches football 
         (can conclude is a male)
 clue 5. hist. and latin teachers are engaged 
         (can conclude diff. genders)
 clue 6. Ames, Brown and Clark went to diff. colleges
```

Comment: You need to change your `Colleges` definition to be `Colleges = [college1, college2, college3]`. Also, I don't think that clue 1 means that they're from the same college?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typing mistake. But removing the given clause from clue1 is not giving write answer. They are from same college.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to give you an answer - that's why I wrote it as a comment.

Comment: And what does clue 2 mean? What can be inferred from it?

Comment: clue2 mean that Ames  is male and can not teach hist or latin because he is not engaged (  clue5 says that hist. and latin teachers are engaged). I think there there will be some more modification in code only . May be there is some clue which I can not translate in right manner.

Comment: Why does being the president of the PTA mean that?

Comment: Mrs. Ames is president of the Plain City P.T.A means Mr. Ames is married ,i.e., not engaged. If you are not understanding any other point , please comment.

Comment: Why does it mean she is married? The `T` in `PTA` means teacher, which Mrs Ames is. Have you edited the question in any way from the original?

Comment: No, I haven't edited it. You can check Q 53 from this link :- http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/~lokylog/images/Notas/la_aldea_de_la_logica/LMI_2013_2/Ayudante/Problemas_Logicos            There is a Mrs Ames and Mr Ames . Acording to american culture , it means that they are married.

Comment: If you want I am posting an edited and more clear version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94448/discussion-between-nazgul-and-enigmativity).